# Expression for when a person tries to tarnish the relationships of others out of spite or for personal gain

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

I recall an English expression that describes when a person is deliberately trying to sabotage the close relationships of other people as a form of revenge or a political maneuver.  For some reason, I always think of the phrase, "[Poisoning the well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisoning_the_well)." But that phrase actually refers to a logical fallacy of the *ad hominem* sort.

My scenario is this:  An employee is fired from a company.  Rather than leaving gracefully, she contacts former employees and tries to undermine their loyalty to the company and to each other.  It could be said that she is ______.

What expression would be appropriate to describe a person in this situation?

Comment: "Undermine" is a great word for the context. (Any reason to not use "undermine"?)  If she were trying to recruit them for her new position, she would be "poaching."

Comment: Does this ring a bell, @RaceYouAnytime, or isn't it the word you recall? Undercut is another option, similar to undermine.

Comment: @Xanne your suggestion is a good one and I upvoted, but it's not the expression I'm trying to recall.  Either way, I appreciate all suggestions.  As for "undermine," I am personally thinking of an idiomatic expression, not a single word.

Comment: Putting someone down? Shoveling sand (out from under someone) is an expression from "inside the beltway."

Comment: Here's another--sabotaging? You already have this term in your description.Sowing seeds of dissension.

Comment: I think as a formal word, _malign_ might be on target.

Answer (score 3):

"out for blood"
this an old expression but still commonly used to mean someone is looking for revenge or to stir up trouble for their own satisfaction.

Answer (score 1):

**bad-mouth** is what comes to mind--usually done behind your back.  Very informal--I don't think I've ever seen it in print.

[definition](https://www.google.com/search?q=bad%20mouthing%20definition&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

ˈbadˌmouth/
verb informal
gerund or present participle: bad-mouthing

criticize (someone or something); speak disloyally of.
   "no one wants to hire an individual who bad-mouths a prior employer"

> **malign** is more explicit, and more formal: [definition](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20malign&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)
>
> 1. adjective
>      evil in nature or effect; malevolent.
>
>    "she had a strong and malign influence"
>
>    synonyms:  harmful, evil, bad, baleful, hostile, inimical, destructive, malignant, injurious;
>
>    literary malefic, maleficent
>      "a malign influence"
>      antonyms:  beneficial
>
>    verb: malign; 3rd person present: maligns; past tense: maligned;
>      past participle: maligned; gerund or present participle: maligning
>
>    1.
>      **speak about (someone) in a spitefully critical manner.**
>
>    "don't you dare malign her in my presence"
>
>    synonyms: defame, slander, libel, blacken someone's name/character, smear, vilify, speak ill of, cast aspersions on, run down, traduce, denigrate, disparage, slur, abuse, revile;

In the proposed sentence, "she is maligning her former employer."

Answer (score 1):

> - **[slander](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/slander?s=t)** a malicious, false, and defamatory statement or report:
>     *a slander against his good name.*

You could say XYZ's *slanderous attacks* on his most loyal ally (friend) proved to be his undoing.

One of the most common ways to blacken the good name of someone is by *spreading* or *circulating*  **[rumours](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rumour)** and in a…

> - **[smear campaign](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/smear-campaign?s=t)** a campaign to tarnish the reputation of a public figure, especially by vilification or innuendo.
>     *He repeated his claim that the allegations were the result of a smear campaign.*

If we apply it to the OP's example we get:

> Rather than leaving gracefully, she contacts former employees and tries to undermine their loyalty to the company and to each other. It could be said that she is **running a smear campaign**.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smear_campaign) says

> A **smear campaign**, *smear tactic* or simply *smear* is an effort to damage or call into question someone's reputation, by propounding negative propaganda. It can be applied to individuals or groups.
>   Common targets are public officials, politicians, political candidates, activists, and ex-spouses. **The term also applies in other contexts such as the workplace.**

In politics, it has its own unique expression, the mudslinging needn't be reserved for opponents, it can also be directed against someone from their own party who is running for the same office.

- [**Negative campaigning**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_campaigning)

Comment: **to get one's own back.**

Answer (score 1):

I do not know any expression. but this person can be called  a **mischief-maker** ;

> Macmillan Dictionary : someone who enjoys causing trouble or disagreement

I , of course , would prefer to use **stirrer**. it is a more exact but informal. it depends on your context.

> Macmillan Dictionary : someone who tries to cause trouble between other people

EDIT: I have found a appropriate expression: **play sb/sth off against sb/sth**

> Collins Dictionary : If you play people off against each other, you make them compete or argue, so that you gain some advantage.

```
Example:Gregory would interview them, and would play one off against the other
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of behavior, unfortunately, is not new.  The book of Proverbs in the Old Testament declares it to be one of seven things the LORD hates:

Proverbs 6:19b KJV... he that soweth discord among brethren.